# WebGL renderer consume too much memory...Browser crash each time

Tags: three.js

I am loading JSON files which has the geometry of each object. If I load a 200MB JSON files, I consume almost 2.5GB of memory to render it and then either the browser crashed or it gives NS_OUT_OF_MEMORY exception. Can anybody suggest some solution to load JSON files which are bigger in size?

Comment: Webgl is a web technology. You don't expect google to return unminified images in a search.

Answer (score 0):

A `200Mb JSON` file is a way too large file to use in a browser. It might work eventually (depending of the final-end user device) but is not an optimized solution.

Therefore, I would suggest you to use `Blender 3D` to reduce the amount of polygons of the object in order to reach at least a `50MB JSON` file. In that scenario, you will be reducing the amount of workload to a quarter.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Decimate
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender

**EDIT:** As you stated that you had no access to CAAD programs at all within the given files. Maybe you can try to apply some solutions stated in this Webpage:

http://goocreate.com/learn/reducing-memory-usage/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Unfortunately I cannot use the Blender3D to reduce the size of JSON File as i donot have control over how json file will be generated.I get JSON files as Input and my task is to render them.Is  there is any other way to reduce the size of JSON or to reduce the amount of memory webglrenderer takes to render those JSON in three.js??

Comment: Check out my edit to the answer. Hope it helps @AtulDhatrak